# Python, how to have separate argument handling and main function?

Tags: python, namespaces

If I have two defs like such:

```
def handle_args(argv=None) 
.
.
.

def main()
.
.
.
```

How can I have the program body consist of:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    handle_args(argv)
    main()
```

and still allow `main` to access the arguments, and allow `handle_args()` to access argv?

My current code (Which I haven't tested yet, I know its wrong and I'm still trying to hack it out) is:

In file ising.py:

```
import extra,sys
global argv
def main(argv=None):

    print('test')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    extra.handle_args(argv)
    main()
    sys.exit(main())
```

In file extra.py:

```
'''
ising -- 3D Ising Model Simulator

ising is a ising model simulator for three dimensional lattices. It has four built in lattice structures
corespodinging to iron, nickel, cobalt and a generic lattice.

@author:     Joseph "nictrasavios" Harrietha
@copyright:  2013 Joseph Harrietha. All rights reserved.
@license:    GNU GPL3
@contact:    nictrasavios@gmail.com
'''
import sys,os,argparse

__all__ = []
__version__ = 0.1
__date__ = '2013-12-20'
__updated__ = '2013-12-20'


def handle_args(argv=None): # IGNORE:C0111
    '''Command line options.'''

    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    else:
        sys.argv.extend(argv)

    program_name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
    program_version = "v%s" % __version__
    program_build_date = str(__updated__)
    program_version_message = '%%(prog)s %s (%s)' % (program_version, program_build_date)
    program_shortdesc = __import__('__main__').__doc__.split("\n")[1]
    program_license = '''%s

    Created by Joseph "nictrasavios" Harrietha on %s.
    Copyright 2013 Joseph Harrietha. All rights reserved.

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

USAGE
''' % (program_shortdesc, str(__date__))

    try:
        # Setup argument parser
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=program_license, formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
        parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", dest="verbose", action="count", help="set verbosity level [default: %(default)s]")
        parser.add_argument('-V', '--version', action='version', version=program_version_message)
        parser.add_argument("-f", "--field", dest="field",default=1, help="Set the value of the magnetic feild. [default: %(default)s]")
        parser.add_argument("-t", "--temp", dest="temp",default=1, help="Set the value of the temperature in Kelvin. [default: %(default)s]")
        parser.add_argument("-l", "--side", dest="side",default=1, help="Set the width/height of the square latice. [default: %(default)s]")
        parser.add_argument("-j", "--excont", dest="excont",default=1, help="Set the value of the Exchange Constant. [default: %(default)s]")
        parser.add_argument("-d", "--data", dest="data",default=10**3, help="Set the number of points to plot for time evolution. [default: %(default)s]")
        parser.add_argument("-m", "--steps", dest="steps",default=10**3, help="Sets the number of Monte Carlo steps. [default: %(default)s]")
        # Process arguments
        args = parser.parse_args()
        verbose = args.verbose

        if verbose > 0:
            print("Verbose mode on")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return 0
    except Exception:
        indent = len(program_name) * " "
        sys.stderr.write(program_name + ": " + repr(Exception) + "\n")
        sys.stderr.write(indent + "  for help use --help")
        return 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your `handle_argv` function should return the parsed arguments in some format the rest of your code can use. Currently you're returning an integer error code of some sort, which is not terribly Pythonic (and you don't even store or check the value anyway).

So, I'd do something like:

```
import sys

def handle_argv(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    # do your parsing here, and don't bother catching exceptions

    return args

def main(args):
    # do whatever, reading args as necessary

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = handle_argv(sys.argv)
    main(args)
```

If you want to move the `handle_argv` function to another module, nothing else needs to change (just import the module and use `whateverthemoduleis.handle_argv(sys.argv)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `optparser`

```
from optparse import OptionParser

def handle_argv():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-u", "--url", dest="url",
                       help="Url to start crawl with")

    options, args = parser.parse_args()
    return options

def main():
    options = handle_argv()
    url = options.url
    print url

main()
```

Comment: Or if you want to be future-proof, use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html), which I have found far superior to optparse in all use cases I have encountered.

Comment: I am using arg parse now.